# Vmware server 2.x remote console on firefox fails when VM does not come up

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-server

The Vmware server 2.x remote console on firefox fails when a VM does not come up.

But this is when I need it to see what happens. The client that does not come up is windwos server 2003.

[image]

The same situation, but another firefox windwo active (the msgbox popup is still the same):

[image]

Comment: have you tried it under IE8?

Comment: good idea. next time this happens I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't state the version of Firefox used to connect. I ran into an issue where my FF was *too* new. i.e. 3.6.x is actually broken, and I had to install an older version so I could connect to VM console on VMware Server.

one other person said - "I downloaded the 3.5 Version again. Then installed aon the computer. No more problems :-) Don't updrade to 3.6 if you want to use vmware-server plugin."

more info at this link:
http://support.mozilla.com/nl/forum/1/564314

the older FF version (3.5.x) made everything work for me.

Comment: I too have had problems with VMWare Server V2.x's management interface under recent Firefox versions, and have just moved to using IE for such access (as most of the places I run VMWare are where I'm running Windows) What options you have if you are running something else as your current desktop environment I'm not sure - it might be worth trying Chromium before rolling FF back to 3.5.x

Comment: qcurtiscu thank you, this should solve it, will install an additional portable 3.5 soon :-)